# I cannot link my image file into my react file

Tags: reactjs

the Image file is located in E:\ItmProject\client\src\images

My import code `import Background from "./2.jpg";`
and `backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")",`

i keep getting `Module not found: Can't resolve './2.jpg' in 'E:\ItmProject\client\src\Components'`
How do i navigate out of the components folder?

Thank you in advance. Forgive my noobness, just started reactjs few days ago. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file tree if your file/image etc is located in the same depth as your current file only then you can use ./file to import a file.
In case it is one unit shallower / above use

> ../

If you are in

> 'E:\ItmProject\client\src\Components'

and the image is located at

> E:\ItmProject\client\src\images\someimage

then use

> ../images/2.jpg

In case image is located directly under src folder then use:

../2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are a in a different folder, what you need to do is go up one folder ../images/2.jpg